# Regular expression is not working if json response value contain special character . how to extract the 'sid' value from below mention json

Tags: jmeter

Regular expression is not working if json response value contain special character . how to extract the 'sid' value from below mention json as "**"sid"?\s*:?\s*"(\w+)"**" is not working as json response contain special character on sid.

0{"sid":"**RhANkc9V7-psbnzmJAAGS**","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":20000,"pingInterval":25000}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\w+` [meta character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) matches "word" characters (alphanumeric and underscores, can be also written as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` character class)

Dash symbol `-` won't be captured so you either need to use wildcard characters instead of "word" something like:

```
sid"?\s*:?\s*"(.*)"
```

Demo:

[image]

Another possible option is removing this starting `0` using [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
prev.setResponseData(prev.getResponseDataAsString().substring(1),'UTF-8')
```

once done you will be able to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)

Answer (score 1):

Your matching group currently scoped to capture ONLY one or more word characters, In order to capture special characters along with word characters you have to tweak your regular expression like below,

```
sid":"(.+?)"
```

In above regular expression, . matches any character (except for line terminators) whereas \w captures only word characters i.e. a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Boundary Extractor if you don't want to mess with the complexity of Regular Expression.

Left Boundary: `sid":"`

Right Boundary: `",`